# parse only first delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, delimiter

Please find below function (**keyvalue.sh**) that parses a configuration file with key value pairs  to return the value for passed argument key.

It works fine, if the value don't have any = (equals to operator), but if the value contains = (equals to) operator, it returns incorrect value.

```
function getValueForKey(){
    while read -r line
    do
        #echo $line
        key=`echo $line | cut -d = -f1`
        value=`echo $line | cut -d = -f2`

        if [ "$2" == "$key" ]; then
            echo $value
        fi;

    done < "$1"
}
```

Please find below sample key-value configuration file (**keys.txt**) :-

```
Scala_Url="http://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.11.8/scala-2.11.8.tgz"
Zookeeper_Url="http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/stable/zookeeper-3.4.10.tar.gz"
Eclipse_Url="http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1135"
```

Also, find below sample execution :-

```
$ls                                                                                                                                                                     
keys.txt  keyvalue.sh                                                                                                                                                   
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$cat keys.txt                                                                                                                                                           
Scala_Url="http://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.11.8/scala-2.11.8.tgz"                                                                                                
Zookeeper_Url="http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/stable/zookeeper-3.4.10.tar.gz"                                                                                  
Eclipse_Url="http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1135"            
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$. keyvalue.sh                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$getValueForKey keys.txt "Scala_Url"                                                                                                                                    
"http://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.11.8/scala-2.11.8.tgz"                                                                                                          
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$getValueForKey keys.txt "Zookeeper_Url"                                                                                                                                
"http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/stable/zookeeper-3.4.10.tar.gz"                                                                                                
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$getValueForKey keys.txt "Eclipse_Url"                                                                                                                                  
"http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file                                                                                                                     
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$cat keyvalue.sh                                                                                                                                                        
function getValueForKey(){                                                                                                                                              
        while read -r line                                                                                                                                              
        do                                                                                                                                                              
                #echo $line                                                                                                                                             
                key=`echo $line | cut -d = -f1`                                                                                                                         
                value=`echo $line | cut -d = -f2`                                                                                                                       

                if [ "$2" == "$key" ]; then                                                                                                                             
                        echo $value                                                                                                                                     
                fi;                                                                                                                                                     

        done < "$1"                                                                                                                                                     
}$                                                                                                                                                                      
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$                                                                                                                                                                       
$
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy and paste it as a code block here. It's very difficult to read otherwise and is impossible for vision impaired folks.

Comment: @JNevill: Thanks! didn't read the part with `=` being part of value.

Comment: @mogli, ...btw, consider trying to get out of the habit of using the `function` keyword. It makes your code incompatible with POSIX sh, but adds no compensating benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `cut` at all for this:

```
getValueForKey(){
    while IFS== read -r key value;
    do
        if [ "$2" = "$key" ]; then
            echo "$value"
        fi;

    done < "$1"
}
```

`read` will split the line on the input separator `=`, and if there are more fields than named variables, it assigns all of the remaining line to the final variable named (in this case, `value`).

But really you should change your format.  At the very least, sort the input and use `look` to find the values.

Answer (score 0):

[William Pursell's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181741/45375) is an effective pure shell solution, but such solutions are inevitably slow, which is why William recommends a key-sorted configuration file combined with `look`.

An alternative that doesn't require sorting is to use `awk`:

```
getValueForKey() {
  awk -F= -v key="$2" '$1 == key { sub(/^[^=]+=/, ""); print }' "$1"
}
```

- `-F=` splits each line into fields by *all* occurrences of `=`
- We can still use `$1`, the 1st field (key field), to compare it to the key value of interest.
- To output the corresponding value, however, a string substitution is used to ensure that the value is output as-is, even if it contains `=` instances:

  - `sub(/^[^=]+=/, "")` replaces (`sub()`) everything from the start of the line (`^`) up to the *first* `=` instance (`[^=]+` matches a nonempty sequence (`+`) of characters *other than* (`^`) `=` followed by `=`) with the empty string, leaving just the value.

Sample call:

```
$ getValueForKey keys.txt 'Eclipse_Url'
"http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1135"
```